# How can I send data from an uploaded file in a button list using an onClick correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, split

I am able to upload multiple csv files and list them with buttons. I want to be able to process the data from whichever file is clicked on and eventually send the processed data to another page creating a plotly chart with that data.

I currently am not able to access the data correctly with an onClick function created when the files are uploaded.

I've tried putting the value(csv) holding the results into the button but then the list doesn't show.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>      
</head>
<body>
    <input style="padding: 20px;" type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
    <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <output id="list"></output>
        <script>
            var memFiles = [];
            document.querySelector('#files').onchange = function(e) {
                var files = e.target.files; // FileList
                var output = [];    
                
                output.push('<div class="list-group list-group-flush">');
                    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; ++i) {
                    if (window.FileReader) {getAsText(f);}
                    else {alert('FileReader are not supported in this browser.');}

                    function getAsText(fileToRead) {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        // Handle errors load
                        reader.onload = loadHandler;
                        // Read file into memory as UTF-8      
                        reader.readAsText(fileToRead);                                
                    }
                    function loadHandler(data) {    
                        var csv = data.target.result;                
                        console.log(csv);
                        memFiles.push(csv);
                        console.log(memFiles);                     
                    }
                    output.push('<a href="#" button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" onclick="processData('+memFiles[0]+')">'+f.name+'</a>('+
                    f.type || 'n/a', ') - ', f.size, ' bytes');
                }      
                document.querySelector('#list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
            };
            function processData(csv) {
                console.log(memFiles);
                console.log(csv);
                var allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the (TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined) problem and when I was sending the file it would return [object File].

The problem happens on ///var allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);

In loadHandler() - console.log(csv) returns the csv values

In processData() - console.log(csv) returns undefined

Comment: Tip #1: Format your code.  Properly indented code is much easier to trace / read / debug.  Tip #2: You've got lots of `console.log`s in place - great what do you get if you `console.log(csv)` where you have `console.log(memFiles)`?  And, Tip #3: Please read how to create an [mcve].

Comment: I've edited to try to simplify and format it with proper indentation, and added any necessary code to be reproducible. In processData() - console.log(csv) returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding quotes to the string being passed to the processData function:

```
output.push('<a href="#" button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" onclick="processData(\'' + memFiles[0] + '\')">' + f.name + '</a>(' +
                f.type || 'n/a', ') - ', f.size, ' bytes');
```

Comment: This solved the (TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined) but I still get undefined for the csv value from memFiles[0]. Any advice on what is needed to pass the correct file data while using the onClick?

Comment: If you just load the page and in the inspector type in memFiles, what shows up in the array? Or what output do you get in the console in the loadHandler function when it's adding csvs to memFIles?

Comment: You could also just look at the HTML being generated in the inspector and see exactly what it's passing to the processData function. Does it look right?

Comment: When I type memFiles into the inspector, I get an empty array. The output from the loadHandler returns an array with the contents of each csv.

Comment: Could you possibly create a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/). It would be easier to debug that way. Thank you!